# fullpage.js scrolling not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios10, fullpage.js

I am setting up a demo page with fullpage.js [here](http://fullpage.de.w01506e0.kasserver.com). Scrolling works fine on my laptop, but my iPhone is not able to scroll to the next section. I have the iOS 10 on an iPhone SE and tested with safari and chrome, both don't work. 
Any suggestions are highly appreciated, as I can easily navigate the demo page of fullpage.js on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to use a slim version of jquery.